# C# - Entity Framework 6.1 - Check for deleted rows in MySql database

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6.1

I'm working in disconnected, database-first scenario and I'm populating a DataGridView with a single database table.
I want to maintain DGV and database table synchronized, so I need to check if someone have updated/deleted table rows (without reloading the entire table).
I've done a method that finds updated DB rows (using TimeStamp) and updates DGV but I don't know how to check if rows have been deleted from DB table (in order to remove those from my DGV).

How can I do that?

Comment: Check if ID in your GDV exist or no in server. If no delete the corresponding ID from DGV

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
With your method, I have to loop all my DGV rows ID every time I want to check for updates.
There isn't a better option?

Comment: Hi I'have the same job but but I put a delay that I can change when I want. So it's a loop but not infinite. Other way is to write a trigger. That's will be more harder for you if you can't write a delay.